# nginx Serve raw content if Accept header is text/plain

Tags: nginx

I have a blog I am running using [deno_blog](https://github.com/denoland/deno_blog) hosted on a Linux VM running Nginx. So I access posts with URLs structured like this: `https:/blog.myblog.com/hello_world` and `hello_world.md` is a file in `/posts` directory. `deno_blog` serves this as HTML upon request.

I have a deployment script that uses pandoc to convert the Markdown formatted blog posts to plain text, which works wonderfully. I host these raw files in a separate directory, `raw/` with the same name as their HTML counterparts.

As is, I can access my blog posts normally through `https:/blog.myblog.com/hello_world`, as well as correctly load the plain text version through `https:/blog.myblog.com/raw/hello_world`

The goal is to have NGINX serve the file within the `raw/` folder if the client's `Accept` header is `text/plain`. However, when I make a request to blog.myblog.com/post with `Accept: text/plain`, I get infinite redirects.

Here is my nginx configuration file that is in `/etc/nginx/sites-available and linked to` sites-enabled/`:

```
server {
        server_name blog.myblog.com;

        root /opt/blog.myblog.com;

        if ($http_accept = "text/plain") {
            return 301 https://blog.myblog.com/raw/$request_uri;
        }

        # Redirect requests on blog.myblog.com to :4096
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4069;
                # Pass on information on requests to provided service
                proxy_set_header HOST $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /path/to/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /path/to/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /path/to/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = blog.myblog.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name blog.myblog.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Using curl -v, you can see it is redirecting to `/raw/raw/raw/.../raw/raw/hello_world`:

```
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Fri, 29 Jul 2022 12:39:44 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 194
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://blog.myblog.com/raw/raw/raw/.../raw/hello_world
```

Comment: From what I understand, the client requests to the server with header `text/plain` and is told the content has moved, make a request to `someurl`. However, client makes said request but header is still `text/plain` so client ends up in a redirect loop. How can I check to see if user has already been redirected once? Check for `raw/` in the url?

Answer (score 0):

I would not implement this with redirects, but using maps. A draft configuration:

```
map $http_accept $filepath {
    "text/plain" /raw$uri;
    default $uri;
}

server {
    ...
    location / {
        try_files $filepath $filepath/ =404;
    }
}
```

The map is used to define `$filepath` variable based on HTTP Accept header. In the above solution, if HTTP Accept header is `text/plain`, `$filepath` has a prefix + URI.

Then in the virtual host configuration, we use the `$filepath` variable to select resource to send to the visitor.

End result should be that when `http://example.com/1.html` is requested with HTTP Accept header that has only `text/plain`, then it is served from the `/raw` directory. Otherwise it is served from the `root`.

Comment: The map makes sense, however there is an issue with handling it in location with `try_files`. With that line enabled within the location block, I get a 404 whenever I visit my blog posts in the browser, and a "text/plain" request returns the HTML.

Comment: Just to make sure, you have files with same names in the `/raw` and `/` directories?

Comment: `/raw` and `/posts`. deno_blog serves the markdown posts as HTML on the base url so a file `posts/hello_world.md` would be accessed at `https://blog.myblog.com/hello_world` or `https://blog.myblog.com/raw/hello_world`

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't act on an `Accept` header compliantly within nginx itself. Doing it with `map` doesn't work because the header can't be understood using only a regular expression.

What you *can* do is send the request to a proxy (or fastcgi or whatever) which does the parse, then returns `X-Accel-Redirect` to the appropriate nginx handler, which you've marked `internal`.

I'm responding to an old thread because I spent far too much time this week figuring this out for myself.